# Trouble generating a deployable binary for a C++ wxwidgets project using Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, wxwidgets, vcredist

I’m having trouble generating a deployable binary for a C++ wxwidgets project using Visual Studio. After the build completes, the exe that is generated does not seem to get installed in any other Windows machine.
Visual studio 2019 is used to create GUI library with openCV included in it. I’m trying to create a standalone executable .exe to run it in any other Windows computer without installing visual studio or opencv in it.
Earlier, while opening the executable file in other computer, it gave error that dll’s are missing for openCV and wxwidgets. So, I have copied the required dll’s from the directories of openCV and wxwidgets bin folder. Now, when I try to execute the exe file, it shows the following error. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

[image: error-1]
[image: error-2]
[image: error-3]
[image: error-4]

Comment: Did you try to compile with `-static` flag?

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to make any changes in visual studio (for including static flag)?

Answer (score 2):

Applications built with the C/C++ runtimes dynamically linked (`/MD[d]`) require the appropriate x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) VC++ redistributables on the target machine. They can be installed from [The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads), or they can be included alongside the application for [local deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/deployment-in-visual-cpp?view=msvc-160#local-deployment).

Also, be sure to only send out non-debug (Configuration = Release) builds.

> ```
> MSVCP140D.dll
> VCRUNTIME140D.dll
> VCRUNTIME140_1D.dll
> ucrtbased.dll
> ```

The `'D'` suffix in the names of those missing DLLs stands for "Debug". Those are the *debug* C/C++ runtime DLLs, which are used by the Configuration = Debug builds, and are installed as part of the Visual Studio setup. They are to be used during development, but not otherwise deployed, per [Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/determining-which-dlls-to-redistribute?view=vs-2019):

> Debug versions of applications and the various Visual C++ debug DLLs are not redistributable.

Answer (score 0):

It also seems that you are using DLL build of wxWidgets and you build OpenCV as DLL.

If you yourself does not create a DLL and your software is one self contained binary ou will be better off using static linking wxWidgets and OpenCV.

And on top of what @dxiv, not everything in MS CRT can be used statically linked. That's why it is strongly recommended to install MS CRT by creating an installer, which should take care of all those dependencies.

HTH.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable suggestions. I will try including the Opencv and wxwidgets statically. My another querry is that, if Instead of using visual studio, if I use any other software can I make this process simple?

Comment: @Rahul, you mean any other compiler? Or IDE? The process will still be the same - you will need to create the installer which will pack up all necessary CRT and system libraries. And of course the same goes for *nix/OSX, except on *nix the installers are different for different distribution. And you will need to google how to make the installer for OSX.

Comment: Thank you @Igor. This is completely new for me. That's why I am facing some difficulties in this. I will try to find a way to make the installer for my target OS. thanks again.

Comment: @Rahul,, what is your target OS?

Comment: Hello Igor, I am targeting for Windows 10 OS. I have sorted out the problem. I was actually missing out the windows redistributables. Once I have installed the VS redistributables 2019 and I have set the library files of OpenCV and wxWidgets in release mode, hence the exe could able to run now. Thanks a lot for your kind help.

Comment: @Rahul, I hope you did create an installer to properly distribute your binaries. When you create an installer, it will pick up all necessary libraries and will install them on the target machine.